# does XElement has something similar XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, xml

I want to make this with XElement:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

mlNodeList nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Title");
```

and get all nodes. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent to your code is:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);
IEnumerable<XElement> nodeList = doc.Descendants("Title");
```

You can call `nodeList.ToList()` if you need a discrete list, but if you just want to iterate, the `IEnumerable` should be fine.

Edit: There are two ways to select nodes. Use `Elements()` if you need the immediate children of a node, or use `Descendants()` if you need *all* children, regardless of how deep they may be.

Comment: hi, thx for answer but your code give me null. My nodeList has 85 elements.

Comment: Where does it give you null? When you enumerate the list? When you call `doc.Elements`? Are the nodes named "Title" (it's case-sensitive)?

Comment: Empty = "Enumeration yielded no results"

Comment: Could you post the XML document? Also, if you're using namespaces, that's a bit of extra code.

Comment: this my code: XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);
                IEnumerable<XElement> nodeList = doc.Elements("FirstName");

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer. I misunderstood what you needed. `Descendants()` will pick ALL children, not just immediate children. I've tested it against the partial document you posted.